# How to clear android app data of my cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova

In my logout option, I need to clear all of my app's data reverting it to a fresh installation state. Basically I need to trigger the same effect as manually doing Settings->Installed Apps->AppName->Clear App Data

Any ideas how to do it?

PS: This is specifically for the android platform only, though if there's a cross-platform solution I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For android version greater then kitkat you can use

```
import android.os.Build.*;
if (VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    ((ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .clearApplicationUserData(); // note: it has a return value!
}
```